# Condense Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, na, data-cleaning

How can I condense this [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe):

```
Date    AAPL   MSFT NASDAQ
1.1.19  NA     NA   NA
2.1.19  2%     NA   5%
3.1.19  3%     NA   6%
...
1.1.19  NA     NA   NA
2.1.19  NA     4%   5%
3.1.19  NA     5%   6%
...
```

to look like:

```
Date    AAPL   MSFT NASDAQ
1.1.19  NA     NA   NA
2.1.19  2%     4%   5%
3.1.19  3%     5%   6%
...
```

Is there a function to not have duplicate dates and NASDAQ values, removes the `NA`s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `summarise_all` (assuming that there are only one non-NA element per 'Date' for each column)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Date) %>%
   summarise_all(na.omit)
```

---

If we have more than one non-NA element and also have some cases with only NAs, either create a `list` column or `paste`

```
df %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ list(if(all(is.na(.))) .[n() + 1] else .[!is.na(.)]))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Date   AAPL      MSFT      NASDAQ   
#  <chr>  <list>    <list>    <list>   
#1 1.1.19 <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
#2 2.1.19 <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [2]>
#3 3.1.19 <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [2]>
```

Also, if some elements are repeated,then we take the `unique` and assuming that there are no completely distinct elements per group

```
df %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) .[n() + 1] else unique(.[!is.na(.)]))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Date   AAPL  MSFT  NASDAQ
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#1 1.1.19 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
#2 2.1.19 2%    4%    5%    
#3 3.1.19 3%    5%    6%
```

Or do the `distinct` first and then do a group by operation

```
distinct(df) %>% 
      group_by(Date) %>% 
      summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ .[!is.na(.)][1])
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Date   AAPL  MSFT  NASDAQ
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#1 1.1.19 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
#2 2.1.19 2%    4%    5%    
#3 3.1.19 3%    5%    6%
```

---

Or in the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we can use `condense`

```
df %>% 
     group_by(Date) %>% 
     condense(data = across(everything(),  ~ .[!is.na(.)]))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Rowwise:  Date
#  Date   data            
#  <chr>  <list>          
#1 1.1.19 <tibble [0 × 3]>
#2 2.1.19 <tibble [2 × 3]>
#3 3.1.19 <tibble [2 × 3]>
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("1.1.19", "2.1.19", "3.1.19", "1.1.19", 
"2.1.19", "3.1.19"), AAPL = c(NA, "2%", "3%", NA, NA, NA), MSFT = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "4%", "5%"), NASDAQ = c(NA, "5%", "6%", NA, "5%", 
"6%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your code unfortunately does not condense the dataframe. I have adjusted the minimal example above to better reflect my situation.

Comment: @Ben You meant both methods are not working?  Can you share more info regarding your concern.  the `list` should keep the elements in a `list` i.e. 1 row for each 'Date'

Comment: @Ben I updated the post based on your example.  I guess one of them is the same output as you showed.  But, I am also keeping other options as well in case your dataset. is more general

Answer (score 1):

Here are some base R solutions:

- Using `split` + `rbind`

```
dfout <- do.call(rbind,
                 c(make.row.names = F,
                   Map(function(z) data.frame(Map(function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)),NA,na.omit(x)),z)),
                       split(df,df$Date))))
```

- Using `ave` + `unique`

```
dfout <- unique(cbind(df[1],
                      sapply(df[-1],
                             function(q) ave(q,df$Date,FUN = function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)),NA,na.omit(x))))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
    Date AAPL MSFT NASDAQ
1 1.1.19 <NA> <NA>   <NA>
2 2.1.19   2%   4%     5%
3 3.1.19   3%   5%     6%
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("1.1.19", "2.1.19", "3.1.19", "1.1.19", 
"2.1.19", "3.1.19"), AAPL = c(NA, "2%", "3%", NA, NA, NA), MSFT = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "4%", "5%"), NASDAQ = c(NA, "5%", "6%", NA, "5%", 
"6%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```